# Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net

I am trying to save a *json* data which stored in a file into an object of below `SearchResults` class:

The JSON:

```
{
    "Collapsing": {
        "CollapsedDocuments": {}
    },
    "FacetDates": {},
    "FacetFields":{
        "TYPE": {
            "DA": 1,
            "FA": 2
        }
    },
    "FacetQueries": {},
    "Header": {
        "params": {             
            "limit": -1,                
            "facet": true,              
            "sort": "",             
            "mincount": 1,              
            "start": 0,             
            "q": "",                
            "field": "",
            "fq": "",
            "rows": 1
        },
        "QTime": 3,
        "Status": 0
    },
    "Highlights": null,
    "IsReadOnly": false,
    "MaxScore": null,
    "NumFound": 1,
    "SimilarResults": {},
    "SpellChecking": {
        "Collation": null,
        "Count": 1,
        "IsReadOnly": false
    },
    "Stats": {}
}
```

The Code:

```
public class SearchResults
    {
        public IEnumerable<CustomResultData> ResultData { get; set; }
        public IDictionary<string, ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, int>>> MyFields { get; set; }
        public IDictionary<string, int> MyQueries { get; set; }
        public int QueryTime { get; set; }
        public int TotalResults { get; set; }
        public IDictionary<string, IDictionary<string, ICollection<string>>> Highlights;
    }

public class CustomResultData
    {
        [SolrUniqueKey("id")]
        public string ID { get; set; }

        [SolrUniqueKey("attr1")]
        public ICollection<string> attr1 { get; set; }
        
        [SolrField("attr2")]
        public ICollection<string> attr2 { get; set; }
    }
```

The below code is for the data transforming one:

```
string jsonResponseStr;
jsonResponseStr = File.ReadAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/my_json_data.json"));

JObject jObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(jsonResponseStr);

var ResultData = jObject;    
var FacetFields = (IDictionary<string, ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, int>>>)jObject["FacetFields"];
var FacetQueries = (IDictionary<string, int>)jObject["FacetQueries"];
var QueryTime = (int)jObject["QueryTime"];
var TotalResults = (int)jObject["TotalResults"];
var Highlights = (IDictionary<string, IDictionary<string, ICollection<string>>>)jObject["Highlights"];

searchResults = new SearchResults  
{
     FacetFields = FacetFields,   // <<---- Error
     ResultData = ResultData,     // <<---- Error  
     FacetQueries = FacetQueries, // <<---- Error
     QueryTime = QueryTime,
     TotalResults = TotalResults,
     Highlights = Highlights      // <<---- Error
};
```

I am getting runtime error `Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary` at the all the initialization lines (which are marked as **<<---- Error** above).

Can anyone give me any clue what is wrong in my code?

Comment: You need to post your json if you need a real help.

Comment: Ok, I have edited the question

Comment: What json you posted? your classes have nothing to do with it

Answer (score 1):

why you just don't do this

```
SearchResults searchResults= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SearchResults>(jsonResponseStr);
```

classes

```
public class SearchResults
{
    public Collapsing Collapsing { get; set; }
    public FacetDates FacetDates { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> FacetFields { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, int> FacetQueries { get; set; }
    public Header Header { get; set; }
    public object Highlights { get; set; }
    public bool IsReadOnly { get; set; }
    public object MaxScore { get; set; }
    public int NumFound { get; set; }
    public SimilarResults SimilarResults { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, object> SpellChecking { get; set; }
    public Stats Stats { get; set; }
}
public class Header
{
    [JsonProperty("params")]
    public Dictionary<string, object> Parameters { get; set; }
    public int QTime { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
}


public class SpellChecking
{
    public object Collation { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public bool IsReadOnly { get; set; }
}


public class SimilarResults
{
}
public class Collapsing
{
    public CollapsedDocuments CollapsedDocuments { get; set; }
}
public class CollapsedDocuments
{
}
public class FacetDates
{
}
public class Stats
{
}
```

Comment: I have tried that as well, but for that case I am getting at the this statement only, as below:

`'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection 1[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair 2[System.String,System.Int32]]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.`

Comment: I have tried this one, and similar to this earlier also. Getting error while initializing `FacetFields` and `FacetQueries` 
Unable to cast object: `'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary\`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary\`2[System.String,System.Int32]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary\`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.ICollection\`1[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair\`2[System.String,System.Int32]]]'.'`

Comment: @iPaul I am always testing my code and it is working properly with a json you posted. Post the real json if it is not working for you. And I don't have any keyvaluepairs in my classes